# possible to have a 'publish to facebook' button on my site?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm building a music events website and want to have a 'share this event' button which publishes the event details on facebook.

this tool looks like exactly what i want: http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?connect_wizard&wizard=stream_publish

however, if i copy the code snippet to new file on my site, it doesn't work.

I'm assuming there's a few lines of extra php/js i need somewhere?

so far i have

```
<body>      
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/connect.php/en_GB" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("89bb37189bede9e30eb07a66b9a1c52a");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callPublish(msg, attachment, action_link) {
      FB.ensureInit(function () {
        FB.Connect.streamPublish('', attachment, action_link);
      });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large hash value in the call to `FB.init()` has to be **your** API key.  [Set one up](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) and you should be good to go.

Comment: so i need to make a facebook application to publish to fb?

Comment: You don't have to make an app, but do you go through that system to generate an API key.

Comment: ps. don't suppose you know a good method publish method like this for twitter do you?!!

Comment: I don't, no.  I'm sure there are plenty of people here on SO that have experience with the Twitter API, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the share widget is the simplest route to take: http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/share.php. You can also use [meta tags](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share/Specifying_Meta_Tags) to help specify what's in the content of the share.